# how to overload php function using javascript variable

Tags: javascript

I have already mentioned variable c_id in javascript

```
<input id="response_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $conversation->getMessageLastID(c_id, $_SESSION['logged_in_user'])?>">
```

Comment: Javascript is client-side, and PHP is server-side. So you can't access Javascript variable from PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can call ajax function with 'c_id' param to populate the value of input field 'response_id'